# Non-static method error when trying to use class in widgets

Tags: php, widgets

I'm trying to call a method into a function widget. The `$this` of the widget is passed to that method, but I get the following error:

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method class_name::method_name() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\themes\...... on line 446
```

Here's what I'm trying to do exactly.

The widget form function:

```
class new_widget extends WP_Widget {
    function form($instance) {
        <?php widget_fields::input($instance, 'title'); ?>
    }
}
```

And the class which I'm using out of the score of the widget class:

```
class widget_fields {
    function input($t, $slug) {
        ?>
        <p>
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name($slug); ?>" value="<?php echo $t[$slug]; ?>" />          
        </p>
        <?php

    }
}
```

Comment: My widget is fine. I just grabbed the part of `function form($instance)`  from it. I wanted to show that I'm trying to add a form input through a class. The issue is just with using `$this` (of the widget) outside it.

Comment: Yeah. Know how to use `$this` out of scope of the widget class without getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

Like the error suggests, your are calling the function statically. If you wanna use it that way you gotta change

```
 function input
```

to:

```
static function input
```

Comment: I'm using a dynamic variable `$this`. I can't call it statically.